# How to deal with ungrouped layers in Affinity Designer?

Tags: affinity-designer

I'm opening a freepik.com vector file in Affinity Designer and the layers show ungrouped. There a millions of layers for a single drawing. How to deal with this?

Do I really need to my hands get on Adobe Illustrator? How to move from there so that I can continue on Affinty Designer?

PS: I'm not at all a fan of Adobe and currently don't own a subscription...so it would be quite a pain. Alternative workarounds would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Affinity Designer can work with groups. Even on imported *.AI and *.EPS files.

So I guess in your case the uploader of the image is to blame. When there are no groups in the file, Affinity Designer will not give you groups.

If you import - for example - this freepik.com image (take the EPS!) into Affinity Designer:
http://www.freepik.com/free-vector/set-of-hand-drawn-christmas-and-new-year-cards_989017.htm

You can clearly see that there are many hierarchical groups!

To answer your question: In the case where the uploader did not preseve structuring groups in the image, unfortunately you have to do the job. But its simple. Just drag over some elements, press Cmd+G (Ctrl+G on Windows) - repeat until you are happy.

Hope, this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem several times and I've concluded that it's more an Affinity problem reading EPS and AI files, specially when there's a lot of styling going on (gradients, shadows, complex highlightings, etc).

Sadly, my only workaround has been opening the file in AI, and then copy/paste the groups to Affinity.

Edit: and as someone previously said, there's also a chance that the freepik author didn't care about grouping the design assets, I've even seen some without expanding strokes and it's a mess :)